# apptainer/singularity multi-stage build with different registries

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry, singularity-container, apptainer

I'm building an apptainer/singularity multi-stage recipe in a gitlab CI environment.
The first step of the recipe is built from an image hosted in a private registry, whereas the second built from an image hosted on dockerhub. Something like this:

```
# First stage
BootStrap: docker
Registry: <my_private_registry>
From: <my_image>
Stage: base
%files
    ...
%post
    ...

# Second stage
BootStrap: docker
Registry: index.docker.io
From: continuumio/miniconda3
Stage: final

%files from base
    ...
%post
    ...
```

Since the first registry is private, in the gitlab CI instance I'm setting the variables `APPTAINER_DOCKER_USERNAME` and `APPTAINER_DOCKER_PASSWORD`, as suggested [here for CI/CD workflow](https://apptainer.org/docs/user/main/docker_and_oci.html#environment-variables).
This allows to build the first stage of the recipe succesfully.

Unfortunately, when the build of the second stage starts, it fails with:

```
> FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I think because the credentials for my private registry are passed to dockerhub in the second stage.

How can I login to different registries in multi-stage builds?

Any idea about how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish what I wanted. The fact was that environment variables overrides other login modes.

So I deleted the `APPTAINER_DOCKER_USERNAME` and `APPTAINER_DOCKER_PASSWORD` environment variables and, [using this method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#option-1-run-docker-login), I added the following `before_script` field to my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
apptainer:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: kaczmarj/apptainer:1.1.3
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
  - privileged
  before_script:
    - echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_TOKEN" | apptainer remote login --username <my_username> --password-stdin docker://$CI_REGISTRY
```

This way, both the private registry (stored in $CI_REGISTRY) and the public
one (dockerhub) are available.

Comment: You can also run into a similar issue with docker registry creds. _e.g.,_ docker pull fails for a public image because the creds being used do not exist in that registry